# Comparing two arrays and setting, extracting the absent elements in the compared array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ajax

I am trying to code a functionnality that enables a `user` to block `subscriptions` in a `tournament` at a certain ranking.
The user is on a page with switch on/off buttons. Every button is related to a `ranking`, everytime the user switches on or off a button, an array containing all the `rankings` that are 'on' (ie: not blocked) is sent to my backend:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

       $('input[name="my-checkbox"]').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', function(event, state) {
          var array = $(".bootstrap-switch-on")
          rankings = [];
          for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
            var ranking = $(array[i]).parent().parent().children().first().html();
            rankings.push(ranking);
          }


          console.log(rankings);
          $.ajax({url: "<%=datatreat_path(params[:tournament_id])%>",
                  dataType: "script",
                  data: {rankings: rankings, "_method":"post"},
                  type: "POST"

                })
        });
```

I have a list of all the rankings. What I need to do know is to check which rankings are actually **not in the array** `rankings` that is sent. Then for each rankings that **is not in the array**, set `@tournament.ranking = false`.

Here's my tournament's table :

```
create_table "tournaments", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.string   "genre"
    t.string   "category"
    t.boolean  "accepted"
    t.integer  "amount"
    t.date     "starts_on"
    t.date     "ends_on"
    t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
    t.string   "address"
    t.string   "city"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "club_organisateur"
    t.float    "latitude"
    t.float    "longitude"
    t.string   "homologation_number"
    t.string   "min_ranking"
    t.string   "max_ranking"
    t.string   "nature",              default: "single"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.integer  "young_fare"
    t.boolean  "NC",                  default: true
    t.boolean  "trentecinq",          default: true
    t.boolean  "trentequatre",        default: true
    t.boolean  "trentetrois",         default: true
    t.boolean  "trentedeux",          default: true
    t.boolean  "trenteun",            default: true
    t.boolean  "trente",              default: true
    t.boolean  "quinzecinq",          default: true
    t.boolean  "quinzequatre",        default: true
    t.boolean  "quinzetrois",         default: true
    t.boolean  "quinzedeux",          default: true
    t.boolean  "quinzeun",            default: true
    t.boolean  "quinze",              default: true
    t.boolean  "cinqsix",             default: true
    t.boolean  "quatresix",           default: true
    t.boolean  "troissix",            default: true
    t.boolean  "deuxsix",             default: true
    t.boolean  "unsix",               default: true
    t.boolean  "zero",                default: true
    t.boolean  "moinsdeuxsix",        default: true
    t.boolean  "moinsquatresix",      default: true
    t.boolean  "moinsquinze",         default: true
    t.boolean  "moinstrente",         default: true
    t.boolean  "quarante",            default: true
```

The 23 last lines each corresponds to a ranking that can be set to false or true ( if the particular ranking is set to false then a user with this particular ranking cannot subscribe to the tournament).
The total list of rankings actually looks like this (this is the format in which they appear in the `rankings` array sent through AJAX :

total_rankings = ['NC', '40', '30/5', '30/4', '30/3', '30/2', '30/1', '30', '15/5', '15/4', '15/3', '15/2', '15/1', '15', '5/6', '4/6', '3/6', '2/6', '1/6', '0', '-2/6', '-4/6', '-15', '-30']

Here's the hash that links the rankings in `total_rankings` and their counterpart columns in the table `tournament`:

```
hash_rankings = { nc: "NC", quarante: "40", trentecinq: "30/5", trentequatre: "30/4", trentetrois: "30/3", trentedeux: "30/2", trenteun: "30/1", trente: "30", quinzecinq: "15/5", quinzequatre:"15/4", quinzetrois: "15/3", quinzedeux: "15/2", quinzeun: "15/1", quinze: "15", cinqsix: "5/6", quatresix: "4/6", troissix: "3/6", deuxsix: "2/6", unsix: "1/6", zero: "0", moinsdeuxsix: "-2/6", moinsquatresix: "-2/6", moinsquinze: "-15", moinstrente: "-30"}
```

How would you code the method that receives the `rankings` array from AJAX compares it to the total_rankings array, detects which rankings are missing in the `rankings` array, and then sets the columns in the tournament table that corresponds to false.

I started coding this but I am a bit confused :

```
def datatreat #this doesnt work
    @tournament     = Tournament.find(params[:tournament_id])
    @rankings = params[:rankings] #renvoit array avec tout les classements autorisés
    rankings_hash = { nc: "NC", quarante: "40", trentecinq: "30/5", trentequatre: "30/4", trentetrois: "30/3", trentedeux: "30/2", trenteun: "30/1", trente: "30", quinzecinq: "15/5", quinzequatre:"15/4", quinzetrois: "15/3", quinzedeux: "15/2", quinzeun: "15/1", quinze: "15", cinqsix: "5/6", quatresix: "4/6", troissix: "3/6", deuxsix: "2/6", unsix: "1/6", zero: "0", moinsdeuxsix: "-2/6", moinsquatresix: "-2/6", moinsquinze: "-15", moinstrente: "-30"}
if @rankings.include?("NC") == false
      @tournament.NC = false
      @tournament.save
    elsif @rankings.include?("40") == false
      @tournament.quarante = false
      @tournament.save
```

ect ect
but the if/elsif method is obviously not working...

Answer (score 0):

If you have control of the front end, the best way to solve this is to use a rails generated form and the check_box form helper, then you can just [serialize](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) the form data with jQuery and send that, which would give you a hash looking like this

```
params: {tournament: { trentecinq: true, trentequatre: false etc...}
```

The form would look like this

```
<%= form_for @tournament do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :trentecinq, '35' %>
  <%= f.check_box :trentecinq %>
<% end %>
```

In which case you can just update the object with params[:tournament] and have them all set correctly (false values as well).

Comment: I tried to follow your advice and added in my view
```<%= form_for @tournament, url: datatreat_path(@tournament), :remote => true do |f| %>
                <%= f.label :NC, 'NC' %>
                <%= f.check_box :NC, name: "my-checkbox" %>```
But when I check my console nothing is sent when I check the box

Comment: The remote true part only means the form will submit via AJAX when you press the submit button on the form. If you want it to update everytime a checkbox is clicked, you will have to write some JS to serialize the form (jQuery function), and submit it via a $.ajax call. You can also fetch the url from the form's action with jQuery.